# Lots of BluetoothHeadsetProxy.exe processes

Tags: windows-7, windows, troubleshooting, bluetooth

I have a weird problem with my Win7 Pro 64: after booting it keeps spawning new BluetoothHeadsetProxy processes. I have 400 of them now and it keeps counting of course slowing down the system enormously. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is Skype installed?

Comment: I do not have Skype installed, but then again, I only have 6 instances running. Seems like it is some Bluetooth SW from WIDCOMM, maybe started together with BTTray.exe. Still.. nothing more I know, from what I know, my notebook does not even have Bluetooth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have Skype installed. It's a bug between Bluetooth Software and Skype.

You can fix that by disable bluetooth support in Skype.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced and then on the link at the bottom that says 'Manage other programs' access to Skype. Remove all bluetooth software there and restart Skype.

When Skype asks you to connect with bluetooth software, click on Deny.